# Add programmatically ListViewItem into Listview in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

So i have this `Dictionary`:

```
 Dictionary<string, double> _statistics;
```

Ans i want to add this `Dictionary` into my `ListView` with 2 columns:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name");
table.Columns.Add("Percent");

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> item in _statistics)
    table.Rows.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
listView.ItemsSource = table;
```

And got an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?)

Edit

I also try this:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public double Percentage { get; set; }
}

        var gridView = new GridView();
        ipStatilistViewsticslistView.View = gridView;
        gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
        {
            Header = "Name",
            DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Name")
        });
        gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
        {
            Header = "Percent",
            DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Percent")
        });

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> item in _statistics)
            listView.Items.Add(new MyItem { Name = item.Key, Percentage = item .Value});
```

And in this case all i can see is my 2 columns heards.

Comment: Why you want to use a `DataTable`?

Comment: I don't care what to use, i only want to populate my ListView with my Dictionary.

Comment: Then you can just write `listView.ItemsSource = _statistics`. ListView.ItemSource will work with anything that implement the `IEnumerable` interface.

Comment: Thats works fine i can see my value inside [ ] braces and also i need the column header, width...

Answer (score 1):

`ItemsControl.ItemsSource` is of `IEnumerable` type and `DataTable` does not implement that interface. You need to use `DataView` instead

```
listView.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

or

```
listView.ItemsSource = new DataView(table);
```

**EDIT**

As for your second example you set view of `ipStatilistViewsticslistView` and populate `listView` with items. I'm guessing it's not the same `ListView`. Also you bind `Percent` column whilst name of the property is `Percentage`

Comment: All i can see now is one column with System.Data.DataRowView insid (i try both options).

Comment: do you use default or custom `ItemTemplate` in the `ListView`?

Comment: In my XAML i only declare the ListView, no other changes was made.

Comment: Check my edit. There is also a problem in your second attempt. With these fixes second attempt should work. However I would set `ItemSource` to instance of `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` and keep adding items to that collection